# Carpeting over a ceramic tile patio- backerboard?

Tags: tile, subfloor, carpet, patio

We have a 20ft x 10' second floor patio outside the master bedroom. Structurally, it is sound.  The tile matches bedroom and rest of house- looks very nice.

However, we want to put a good outdoor carpet on the patio. While yes, the tile is same as in the house, based on past experience, a carpet traps that chalky dust that collects on a tile patio so you don't track it into the house.

Plus the carpet deadens sounds, etc.  We don't want to destroy the tile for resale and I know that glue/nailers will destroy the tile.

So.... would placing exterior grade plywood subfloor and/or backboard over the tile and screwing that into just a few spots around the perimeter work to minimize tile damage?

The patio gets lots of sun and we get very, very little rain on it due to a significant roof overhang all the way around.

Or, perhaps put a plastic barrier between tile and backerboard would work as well.  Then, glue down the carpet as normal?

Comment: what about a small dab of glue in the centers of the tiles around the outside edge, put carpet down, time to pull carpet use a solvent to desolve the glue.

Comment: Are you opposed to a nice, large, outdoor area rug? That seems to be the most simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

Most good outdoor grade carpets have a rubber mesh bottom.  Just hit lay down 8-10 double sided tape pieces.  The adhesive will come right off tiles with hot water.  If you want to allow for the carpet to be washed you can use Velcro strips.

Answer (score 0):

no - the plywood will rot and grow mold and fungus.  it will be a nightmare.